# UWP Listview freezes app for a few seconds

Tags: listview, uwp, loading

When I navigate to a frame containing a listview, my app freezes for a few seconds while it fetches the data. I tried showing a loading textblock in my main menu, but it only starts showing a split second before my app navigates to the frame containing the listview.

Is there any way I can either speed up the loading, or show the loading message before the app freezes?

**Main menu button**

```cs
        private void moviesClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            txtLoading.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            Frame.Navigate(typeof(MovieList));
        }
```

**Constructor of listview page **

```cs
public sealed partial class MovieList : Page
    {
        private MoviesViewModel vm;

        public MovieList()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().AppViewBackButtonVisibility = AppViewBackButtonVisibility.Visible;
            SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().BackRequested += (s, e) =>
            {
                // Handle the Back pressed  
            };
                // vm contains the list loaded into the view
            vm = new MoviesViewModel();
        }
    }
```

**Viewmodel**

```cs
   public class MoviesViewModel
    {
        public ObservableCollection<MovieGeneral> movies { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<MovieGeneral>();
        private MovieService movieService = new MovieService();

        public MoviesViewModel()
        {
            movies = movieService.LoadMovies();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try to make LoadMovies async... so the UI-Thread can update your screen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use a network request, such as `HttpClient`, you can make asynchronous calls through the`HttpClient.GetAsync()`method, which means that the current UI thread will not be frozen.

But you cannot use `await` in the constructor to make asynchronous calls, so it is recommended that you do not put the `LoadMovie` method in the `MoviesViewModel`'s constructor, but instead create a new method, and then make asynchronous calls after the `MoviesViewModel` initialization is completed, like this:

**ViewModel**

```cs
public class MoviesViewModel
{
    ...

    public async Task LoadMovies()
    {
        movies = await movieService.LoadMovies();
    }
}
```

**Page**

```cs
public sealed partial class MovieList : Page
{
    private MoviesViewModel vm;

    public MovieList()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        // other code

    }
    protected async override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        vm = new MoviesViewModel();
        await vm.LoadMovies();
    }
}
```

For more on asynchronous programming, you can check out this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/threading-async/call-asynchronous-apis-in-csharp-or-visual-basic)

Best regards.